# Access contact associated with incoming call for iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

I know this is possible because the Martian Notifier [iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/martian-notifier/id850036614?mt=8) does it as shown in the screenshot below (third-party product similar to apple watch). However, I can't find any code examples. The [CTCall](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CTCall) class doesn't seem to provide any useful Contact or Caller Id metadata.

[image]

Comment: External Bluetooth devices can use the ANCS protocol to get this information from the phone. You can't do it in an app.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 - if you want to write an answer with a link to ANCS I'll accept it